# Change CSS from the biggest SQL sum

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have this table name "**casillas**"

```
            colum_1     colum_2     colum_3     colum_4
        ___     ___     ___     ___   ___   ___   ___
field_1 |   46654   |   8463    |   1284    |   1654
field_2 |   14668   |   547896  |   11563   |   4565
field_3 |   6486    |   54763   |   15697   |   56776
field_4 |   45684   |   5668    |   989     |   48678
```

And I display it in PHP like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(colum_1) FROM casillas");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$colum_1_result = $row['SUM(colum_1)'];
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(colum_2) FROM casillas");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$colum_2_result = $row['SUM(colum_2)'];
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(colum_3) FROM casillas");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$colum_3_result = $row['SUM(colum_3)'];
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(colum_4) FROM casillas");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$colum_4_result = $row['SUM(colum_4)'];
}

echo '<table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                                <td>Results:</td>
                                <td>'.$colum_1_result.'</td>
                                <td>'.$colum_2_result.'</td>
                                <td>'.$colum_3_result.'</td>
                                <td>'.$colum_4_result.'</td>
                </tr>
</table>';
```

My question is: is there a way make it bold or change the CSS from the cell when the value is bigger from the others?

In this case, it would be the one from **colum_2**

Comment: Here you have a jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/esfj9/

Comment: Is there a way to do it but horizontally insted of vertically??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't hit the database several times when you can get everything you need in one request. You can get all your sums and a greatest value with a query like this

```sql
SELECT sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, GREATEST(sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4) max_sum
  FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(colum_1) sum1, SUM(colum_2) sum2, SUM(colum_3) sum3, SUM(colum_4) sum4
  FROM casillas
) q
```

Sample output from the query:

```
|   SUM1 |   SUM2 |  SUM3 |   SUM4 | MAX_SUM |
----------------------------------------------
| 113492 | 616790 | 29533 | 111673 |  616790 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a76b3/1)** demo

Now in php code compare a sum value with the greatest value and if it's a match set a CSS class for the corresponding `<td>`. Obviously you need to define that style somewhere preferably in an external style sheet.

```php
<style>
    .maxsum {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<?php 

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, GREATEST(sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4) max_sum
  FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(colum_1) sum1, SUM(colum_2) sum2, SUM(colum_3) sum3, SUM(colum_4) sum4
    FROM casillas
) q";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>Results:</td>
                <td '. ($row['sum1'] == $row['max_sum'] ? 'class="maxsum"' : '') .' >'.$row['sum1'].'</td>
                <td '. ($row['sum2'] == $row['max_sum'] ? 'class="maxsum"' : '') .' >'.$row['sum2'].'</td>
                <td '. ($row['sum3'] == $row['max_sum'] ? 'class="maxsum"' : '') .' >'.$row['sum3'].'</td>
                <td '. ($row['sum4'] == $row['max_sum'] ? 'class="maxsum"' : '') .' >'.$row['sum4'].'</td>
            </tr>
    </table>';
}
```

On a side note: `mysql_` extension is deprecated and no longer supported. Therefore consider to switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.